# This expression is not callable. Type 'SpringRef<{ scroll: number; }>' has no call signatures

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-spring

I'm trying to set the current scroll position using useSpring from react-spring and useCallback from react. But i'm getting this error

> This expression is not callable.   Type 'SpringRef<{ scroll: number; }>' has no call signatures.

when I try to set the position

the relevant code is

```js
const [{ scroll }, set] = useSpring(() => ({ scroll: 0 }))
const onScroll = React.useCallback(e => void set({ scroll: e.target.scrollTop / (window.innerHeight / 2) }), [])
```

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/1359)